# apache redirect (the trailing slash issue)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Amazon ELB (80->8080, 443->8080) -> Apache server (port 8080)

My apache server has /var/www/html as the root.  /var/www/html/customer is a symlink to /mnt/content/customer.

```
http://company.com/customer redirects to http://company.com/customer/
https://company.com/customer redirects to http://company.com/customer/
```

I want: https://company.com/customer redirects to **https**://company.com/customer/

Note the trailing slash and https to http.  I want to stay on https.

I've tried the following in my /mnt/content/customer/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://company.com/$1/ [L]
```

I still redirect to http.  My base file is index.html.  I've tried different suggestions on the net, but I'm missing something.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/customer/$1 [R,L]
```

I needed the X-Forwarded-Proto because the ssl was on an Amazon ELB, not the server.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.*?[^/][\s?]
RewriteRule ^$ https://company.com/customer/ [R,L]
```

Comment: that redirects to https://company.com//. Note the two slashes at the end.  I need https://company.com/customer/ What am I missing?

Comment: "The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Note, both `http://company.com/customer and https://company.com/customer` show it is redirecting, but it is in an endless loop.